# How to use ThreadPooling

Tags: c#, threadpool

ThreadPooling. I have this program that scrapes productdata. In my current context I get a bunch of indexes (113978 indexes) and then foreach index i pull the product data (hopefully i will get 113978 products in the end).

But this is going to take forever since every product has a number of different data it pulls down f.x. product images as byte arrays and list of product features.

I have looked up examples on the internet, and found this example

```
//Sample 02: Define Task/Wait Callback function
        private static void
            TaskCallBack(Object ThreadNumber)
        {
            string ThreadName = "Thread " + 
                ThreadNumber.ToString();
            for (int i =1; i < 10; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(ThreadName 
                    + ": " + i.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ThreadName 
                + "Finished...");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Sample 03: Create Thread Pool
            for (int task = 1; task < 51; task++)
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                    new WaitCallback(TaskCallBack), task);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
```

Since I've never worked with ThreadPools before I am very unsure how to convert my function to use this example code.

My function:

```
public static List<Product> GetAllProductsFromIndexes(List<IndexModel> indexes) {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            foreach (IndexModel index in indexes)
            {
                Product product = new Product();

                byte[] unconvertedByteArray;
                string xml;
                string url = @"https://data.Icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/en/";
                unconvertedByteArray = DownloadIcecatFile(index.IndexNumber.ToString() + ".xml", url);
                xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unconvertedByteArray);

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

                GetProductDetails(product, xmlDoc);

                XmlNodeList nodeList =
               (xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductFeature"));

                product.FeaturesLink = GetProductFeatures(product, nodeList);

                nodeList =
               (xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductGallery/ProductPicture"));

                product.Images = GetProductImages(nodeList);

                products.Add(product);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Passed in {indexes.Count} indexes, recieved {products.Count} products");
            return products;
        }
```

Comment: To a first approximation, `Parallel.ForEach` and `Enumerable.AsParallel` (parallel LINQ) are far easier ways to parallelize an otherwise sequential calculation than explicit thread management (and that's before we consider `Task`s and `async`/`await` for code that can be rewritten that way).

Comment: If the list of items isn't dynamic, perhaps `Parallel.ForEach` is what you'd prefer. It's the multithreaded equivalent of a `foreach` and is deffered to the ThreadPool behind the scenes.

Comment: Okay but would that give me what I need in the form that I could get f.x. 20 products data at the same time?
I need to reduce the time it uses alot compared to singlethread

Comment: @S.Bojesen Yes, if your bottleneck is CPU operations. But may be you have slow internet connection speed (or slow download speed at site you are getting information from) and you limited by it. Try to use Parallel.ForEach and see. It's very easy.

Comment: Maybe -- it depends. You can certainly ask `Parallel.ForEach` to spawn up to 20  tasks (`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`) but in many cases, when you're invoking an external website, the bottleneck is that site. It may simply not offer the results of 20 requests at the same speed as that of 1.

Comment: @JeroenMostert can you please make your comment into an answer so i can mark the question as answered? thanks